# PHP Select multiple desc limit's?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, limit

In my sql table i had more then 300000 entries.

```
 $marketname = more then 200 !
```

with this select i can see the last 15 entries.

```
$sql = "SELECT price FROM markets where market = '" . $marketname . "' order by time desc LIMIT 15,1";
$sql = "SELECT price FROM markets where market = '" . $marketname . "' order by time desc LIMIT 15,1";
```

and so on for the last 30, 60, 120.

```
$sql = "SELECT price FROM markets where market = '" . $marketname . "' order by time desc LIMIT 30,1";
$sql = "SELECT price FROM markets where market = '" . $marketname . "' order by time desc LIMIT 60,1";
```

But is there a combination of all, because when i show it on one page its very very slow with 200 markets!!

like..

```
$sql = "SELECT price FROM markets where market = '" . $marketname . "' order by time desc LIMIT 15,1 AND LIMIT 30,1 AND LIMIT 60,1 AND LIMIT 120,1";
```

Comment: I honestly have no idea what you are trying to do; Plus.. ".$marketname." makes it look like this is ripe for sql injection?. Can you rephrase the problem you are experiencing? Are you trying to show the last 200? If so, remove the limit N,1 <- ,1 part.. since that means return 1 record.

Comment: fox example i had 200 rows. Now i would show the last price, the 2nd last, the 15last, the 30last, the 60last, the 120last of every market.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try to not do SQL injection style SQL. Use PDO or MySQLi with prepared statements. With that in mind, do not limit your query's last part.

```
SELECT price FROM markets WHERE market = :marketName ORDER BY time DESC limit 100
```

Would query the price of the market by marketname (prep statement), order it and limit it to 100 records.

Comment: ok! but.. i will exactly get the last price, the 2nd last, the 10last, 30last

Comment: Since you are already descending by time and selecting by market... you should get an array with all the prices.. if you select price and time you can easily traverse the array to get each price.